# Error in ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

ImageView is not working on the phone but showing fine in the preview section. I have used the debugger and got to know that all other parts are working fine. Just when I use ImageView then the application doesn't open up.

I tried searching for an answer and tried few like changing the size of images but it's still not working.

Current Image Sizes - 284kb and 609kb respectively.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#263238"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:scaleX="1"
            android:scaleY="1"
            android:src="@drawable/coffee" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/head"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="25sp"
            android:text="Cup And Coffee"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/creamText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="Whipped Cream : "
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/creamCheckbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:buttonTint="#fafafa" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/coffee1"
            android:layout_marginStart="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="150sp"
            android:layout_height="150sp"
            android:src="@drawable/coffee2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:background="#000a12"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="115sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:background="#000a12"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="35sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="215sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:background="#000a12"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="50sp"
            android:layout_height="50sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="315sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:background="#000a12"
            android:text="-"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="35sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="QUANTITY : "
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="215sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="QUANTITY : "
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/q4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="330sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="TOTAL :"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="$ 0"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="215sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="TOTAL :"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="295sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="$ 0"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="GRAND TOTAL :"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="25sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/grandtotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="260sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
            android:text="$ 0"
            android:textColor="#fafafa"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? app crashes?
If so, which res/drawable folder is the image in and what are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: I don't get any exception. On running on the phone, it just blink and closes down.

Images are in drawable folder not drawable-v24. 

Image1 - 2240 × 3360
Image2 - 2240 × 3360

Comment: If your device is high res, then you probably have a memory problem as the image is large and getting even larger because it's in drawable folder. Just for testing try putting the image in drawable/xxhdpi and see if it works

Comment: I reduced the resize the images and its working fine now. Thank you

Comment: Also use sp for font sizes only. Use dp for widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Your image is in too high resolution and app is closed due the `OutOfMemory` exception. That is the first thing. Second thing is to never put images directly into `XML` except for the icons which you created following Android rules. Always practice to download images at `runtime` handling possible exceptions. And for that use some external library like `Glide` or `Picasso` which have built in handling exceptions and caching the images.